# Inserting entity in CoreData and EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data

I am writing a program that synchronizes with a server. Synchronization is run in foreground but using LRResty and delegates to get the responses. Randomly, while I run the synchronization, I get **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** signal running this code or some other insertion/relationship adding in CoreData:

```
WorkoutExerciseSet *set = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"WorkoutExerciseSet" inManagedObjectContext:mObjContext];
```

Therefore I was thinking the error is given because this code isn't actually run on the main thread. Could that be the reason? Which is the best way to solve it?

Comment: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` generally comes from sending a message to a deallocated object. You haven't posted enough code to determine where the problem is being created.

Comment: is `WorkoutExerciseSet` an entity or a relationship? NSEntityDescription will return an NSEntity instance so you need to reference your entity name not the relationship. Get a reference to the entity and then fetch the set by accessing the relevant relationship. i.e. `NSEntity *person = [....` and then grab the workouts with `NSSet *workouts = [person valueForKey:@"workoutExerciseSet"]`

Answer (score 0):

The only possible source of EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the line of code given is that the `mObjContext` has a nil value. You are losing your NSManagedObjectContext object somewhere along the line.

Based on that one line of code, you are probably not using assessors correctly. The managed object context is almost always an attribute of the object holding the insertion code so the line should probably look like:

```
WorkoutExerciseSet *set = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"WorkoutExerciseSet" inManagedObjectContext:self.mObjContext];
```

... to make sure the context object is properly accessed. Likewise, when you set the attribute value it should be:

```
self.mObjContext=someManagedObjectContext;
```

Comment: These are good points, thanks, seemed like the problem was accessing the same ManagedObjectContext from different threads, so probably this was the cause for **EXC_BAD_ACCESS**.
I solved it putting a lock on ManagedObjectContext so that even if accessed from different threads it is accessed sequentially.

Comment: It's bad practice to use a context on more than one thread. If you have multiple threads, you should create a separate context for each thread.